# Pandas -selecting data from last minute of hour for 24hr data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Pandas beginner here.

I have a 24 hour time series in minutes, with a cumulative value in column A:

```
Time                Energy
11-01-2017 10:14    19.14634168
11-01-2017 10:15    19.14702618
11-01-2017 10:16    19.14719065
11-01-2017 10:17    19.14719065
…   
11-01-2017 23:56    19.47694149
11-01-2017 23:57    19.4771605
11-01-2017 23:58    19.47753776
11-01-2017 23:59    19.47801377
```

I would like to know what the value of column A is at the end of every hour (dd-mm-yyy hh:**59**), and save this data in a csv file, with an extra colum added to show the hour. The result would look like this:

```
   Time             Hour  Energy
   11-01-2017 00:59    1     02.0000000
   11-01-2017 01:59    2     04.1234554
   11-01-2017 02:59    3     06.1234554
   ...
   11-01-2017 23:59    24    19.4780137
```

Should I iterate the timeseries based on the seconds value of 59, or is it easier to just pluck the value in Column A every 60 rows, given there will always be 1440 rows (1440 minutes)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
df['hour'] = df.Time.dt.hour + 1
df1 = df[df.Time.dt.minute == 59]

print (df1)
                 Time     Energy  hour
7 2017-11-01 23:59:00  19.478014    24
```

Comment: Thanks... I've having difficulty adding the 'hour' column. The problem is that the column isn't actually named 'Time'; it is blank/index column. How does reference this? Use 'Index' instead of 'Time'?

Comment: Exactly, and remove `dt` - `df['hour'] = df.index.hour + 1`

Comment: what if i just want to get the data for every last minute.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855037/sending-tweets-notification-with-python-script?noredirect=1#comment92628720_52855037

Answer (score 1):

If your time values are regular with no gaps as you say you can use slicing semantics with a step arg:

```
df.iloc[::60]
```

if the first entry is not the first minute, like you showed then just offset the first arg:

```
df.iloc[45::60]
```

As minute 14 is 45 off minute 59

**timings**

```
In [176]:
s = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2016,1,1), freq='1min', periods=10000)
s

Out[176]:
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-01 00:01:00',
               '2016-01-01 00:02:00', '2016-01-01 00:03:00',
               '2016-01-01 00:04:00', '2016-01-01 00:05:00',
               '2016-01-01 00:06:00', '2016-01-01 00:07:00',
               '2016-01-01 00:08:00', '2016-01-01 00:09:00',
               ...
               '2016-01-07 22:30:00', '2016-01-07 22:31:00',
               '2016-01-07 22:32:00', '2016-01-07 22:33:00',
               '2016-01-07 22:34:00', '2016-01-07 22:35:00',
               '2016-01-07 22:36:00', '2016-01-07 22:37:00',
               '2016-01-07 22:38:00', '2016-01-07 22:39:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=10000, freq='T')

In [179]:    
%timeit s[s.minute == 59]
%timeit s[::60]

1000 loops, best of 3: 639 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.5 µs per loop
```

So here slicing is ~20x faster

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I have used a combo of this slicing and the suggestion above by jezrael for the solution.

Comment: @wazzahenry it depends on the form of the index here, where you have regular values then slicing is faster but the other solution will work irrespective as it looks for equality