# sending tweets notification with python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having a data-frame in which i am having tweets and ID and other details. I am sending an alert for every new tweet having some word in it and with the below code i am filtering them out.

```
my_list = ['Maintenance','Scheduled','Downtime']
ndata=data[data['Tweets'].str.contains("|".join(my_list), regex=True)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

suppose i am sending notification for for ID at index 2 then i want to store the ID in some variable and then when the new tweet list will come it should only send the notification for new ID which is at index 0 and 1 and not the old ones again.

I am able to do the filtering with the below code but how i can make this process dynamic if i have to run this script every minute.

```
ndata.iloc[:ndata[ndata.ID == 1052107168068132864].index.item()]
```

I want to make this whole process dynamic.

Comment: So you mean every minute you are given a DataFrame which some rows are repetitive comparing to the previous DataFrame, and you want to prevent sending email to the same ID's again?

Comment: @MeHdi exactly.. Its not like i am storing any datafrme... I am just scraping tweets and converting it to a dataframe for doing various filteration and analysis.   BUT YOU GOT MY POINT WHAT I WANNA DO..If i already have sent a notification for a particular tweet ID then i don't wanna send it again..

Comment: So you need to kinda persist to whom you have already sent notification, can you use a Database?

Comment: @MeHdi No No...its not about whom we are sending the notification..its just the notification should not go out for the same tweet twice. IF there is a new tweet then the notification should go else nothing should happen. Here tweet ID is a unique key to identify each tweet....DO I MAKE SENSE?

Comment: Ok, somehow you need to know what was the last tweet for which you sent a notification, how can you do that? can you persist the ID or time of the last tweet you sent notification for it?

Comment: Yes ..... so that is teh challenge... i am thinking to store the tweet ID in a vriable say id for which i sent the notification and when the new tweet list will come i will compare the id and ignore all the old tweets by using ndata.iloc[:ndata[ndata.ID == 1052107168068132864].index.item()] .... else i am thinking if i can just get the tweets for the last minute and keep running the script every minute..... I mean if you have any suggestion. As nobody wants to get the same notification twice.